# Renaming a copied file by adding '-copy-' followed by a number

Tags: javascript

I am copying names using javascript, and a name should not duplicate. Then I am adding a counter with `-copy-`. For example, if the name is `joy`, then the result of the copy should be `joy-copy-1`. If I copy `joy` again, the resulting name should be `joy-copy-2`.

I am using a `counter` but it is not correct. Because `counter` is always increasing, it is not depending on `name` value.

**SAMPLE CODE:**

```
 var counter = 1;
 var index = _.find(documents, function (o) {
   console.log("--------------->", counter++);                    
   o.name = o.name + '-copy-' + counter;
   return o._id.$oid == CompareValue;
 });
```

I am retrieving `name` from a JSON file and adding the `counter` number. But it is not correct.

**Expected output**
**For Example**

> ***Name is joy;***
>   **After Copy**
>   joy-copy-1
>   **Again copy joy**
>   joy-copy-2
>   **Again copy joy**
>   joy-copy-3
>   **If I copy joy-copy-3 then,**
>   joy-copy-3-copy-1
>   **Again copy joy-copy-3**
>   joy-copy-3-copy-2
>   [image]

Comment: Can you share `documents` data?

Comment: how to bifurgate that this is 1st time or second time copy...Is again copy or after copy means paste ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a regular expression for checking the copy and take the number for incrementing.

```js
function update(string) {
    var match = string.match(/^(.+-copy-)(\d+)$/);
    return match && match[2] !== '3'
        ? match[1] + (+match[2] + 1)
        : string + '-copy-1';
}

var i = 10,
    string = 'joy';

while (i--) {
    console.log(string = update(string));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: console.log(update('joy-copy-3')); it should be print joy-copy-3-copy-1

Comment: please add some example, what you expect and why.

Comment: Please look at my expacted output.

Comment: your code 60% correct as per my expactation. Only when found joy-copy-3 then it should treat as new name and final name should be joy-copy-3-copy-1. Same as copy paste. For example if you copy the any folder then paste  then see what is the final name of folder. I am following the same approach.

Comment: again please add some more use cases.

Comment: Sure, I will upload

Comment: so where do you decide to increment or put another copy to it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a map of name counters instead?

```js
 var counters = [];
 
 function copy(name){
  return name + '-copy-' + (++counters[name] || (counters[name] = 1));
 }
 
 console.log(copy("joy"));
 console.log(copy("joy-copy-1"));
 console.log(copy("joy-copy-1-copy-1"));
 
 console.log(copy("joy"));
 
 console.log(copy("joy-copy-2"));

console.log(copy("joy"));
```

```
var counters = [];

 var index = _.find(documents, function (o) {
        //console.log("--------------->", counter++);                    
        o.name = o.name + '-copy-' + (++counters[o.name] || (counters[o.name] = 0));
        return o._id.$oid == CompareValue;
      });
```

Comment: when I copy again original name. Then Again it it creating same name. Like Joy copy first time. Then joy-copy-0 again I am copy joy then again joy-copy-0 is making as per your code. It should be joy-copy-1

Comment: I added a snippet that uses the logic I showed earlier, which is similar to the one you started. I used all the examples you put.